# Homogeneous and inhomogeneous recurrences for a sequence

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, integer-partitions, integer-sequences

Some integer sequences have both homogeneous and inhomogeneous recurrence relations.  If you know one, are there techniques for figuring out the other?  (Or seeing if the other exists?)  Below is an example and a related particular sequence I'm interested in.

The sequence [OEIS A002620](https://oeis.org/A002620) satisfies $a(n) = 2a(n-1) - 2a(n-3) + a(n-4)$ and also $a(n) = a(n-2) + n - 1$, which is perhaps a nicer expression.  It's easy to confirm that these both lead to the same generating function for the sequence.  If you knew only one of them, could it help you find the other?

For an example without a known answer (at least not to the OEIS), the sequence [A097701](https://oeis.org/A097701) satisfies
\begin{align}
a(n) =& \; 2a(n-1) + a(n-2) - 3a(n-3) - a(n-4) + a(n-5) + 3a(n-6) \\ & {}- a(n-7) - 2a(n-8) + a(n-9).
\end{align}
Does it also satisfy an inhomogeneous recurrence?  (If so, hopefully of smaller degree.)

(Not essential to the question, but in case anyone's wondering: The two sequences are connected by interpretations concerning integer partitions.  The first sequence counts partitions made with parts 2 and two kinds of 1s.  The second sequence is the analogous count for allowed parts 3, two kinds of 2s, and two kinds of 1s.)

Comment: I think you would use the fact that $b(n) = n-1$ has a homogeneous recurrence when you start with $a(n) = a(n-2) + n - 1$ and try to get a homogeneous recurrence for $a(n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is

> Some integer sequences have both homogeneous and inhomogeneous recurrence relations. If you know one, are there techniques for figuring out the other? (Or seeing if the other exists?)

In many cases of homogeneous recurrence relations there is the
existence of a rational generating function.

For example,
[OEIS sequence A097701](https://oeis.org/A097701) has the g.f.

$$ A(x):=\frac1{(1-x)^2 (1-x^2)^2 (1-x^3)} = 1 + 2x + 5x^2 + \cdots. $$

Multiply this by a nontrivial factor of the denominator (if it exists)

$$ P(x):=(1-x) (1-x^2)^2 (1-x^3) = \\
1 - x - 2 x^2 + x^3 + 2 x^4 + x^5 - 2 x^6 - x^7 + x^8  $$

to get

$$ A(x)P(x) = \frac1{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots. $$

Thus, the sequence satisfies the inhomogeneous equation
$$ a(n)=a(n-1)+2a(n-2)-a(n-3)-2a(n-4)-\\
a(n-5)+2a(n-6)+a(n-7)-a(n-8)+1. $$

Similar results come from other choices of $P(x)$. Also the
procedure is reversible.

As an important special example, consider
[OEIS sequence A002620](https://oeis.org/A002620)
"Quarter-squares" with g.f.

$$ A(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3(1+x)} = x^2 + 2x^3 + 4x^4 +
6x^5 + \cdots. $$

Use seven polynomial divisors of the denominator to get
recurrenes

\begin{align} 
a(n) &= -a(n-1) + n(n-1)/2, \\
a(n) &= a(n-1) + \lfloor n/2\rfloor, \\
a(n) &= a(n-2) + (n-1), \\
a(n) &= 2a(n-1) - a(n-2) + 1 - \text{mod}(n,2), \\
a(n) &= a(n-1) + a(n-2) - a(n-3) + 1, \\
a(n) &= 3a(n-1) - 3a(n-2) + a(n-3) + (-1)^n, \\
a(n) &= 2a(n-1) - 2a(n-3) + a(n-4).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know of a "suitable polynomial" that would show the A000260 generating function, $A(x) = 1/((1-x)^2(1-x^2))$, satisfies $a(n) = a(n-2)+n-1$?

Comment: @BrianHopkins Thanks for that comment! I have sharpened that phrase. Try $P(x)=(1-x)^2$ for A000260.

Comment: Thanks again, Somos, for both the clarification and the suggestion for $P(x)$.  I think $P(x) = 1 - x^2$ is actually what I want, as that gives the correct homogeneous part, $a(n-2)$.  I'm not yet clear on how $A(x) P(x) = 1/(1-x)^2$ leads to the inhomogeneous part of the recurrence, $n - 1$.  Also, it doesn't seem that each possibility for $P(x)$ leads to an inhomogeneous recurrence.  Once I understand those issues better, I'll look for other inhomogeneous recurrences for the degree 9 linear recurrence.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Oops! You are correct. It is $1-x^2$. I have added the complete list now.

Comment: Wonderful and thorough, thanks very much.  So there *is* something for each $P(x)$ choice.  There's a rough trade-off between degree of the homogeneous portion and complexity of the inhomogeneous part (including but not restricted to the degree of $n$).

Comment: As a postscript, for A097701, using $P(x) = 1-x^3$ gives the recurrence $a(n) = a(n-3) + (n + 2)(2n(n + 4) - 3(-1)^n + 3)/48$.  The choice most helpful to me turns out to be $P(x) = (1-x^2)(1-x^3)$ which gives $A(x)P(x) = 1/((1-x)^2(1-x^2))$, the generating function for A002620.

Answer (score 0):

From the inhomogenoeus $a(n)=a(n-2)+n-1$ you get $a(n-1)=a(n-3)+n-2$; subtracting gives $a(n)-a(n-1)=a(n-2)-a(n-3)+1$. From that, you get $a(n-1)-a(n-2)=a(n-3)-a(n-4)+1$, and subtracting again gives $a(n)-2a(n-1)+a(n-2)=a(n-2)-2a(n-3)+a(n-4)$ which rearranges to $a(n)=2a(n-1)-2a(n-3)+a(n-4)$, which is your homogeneous.

Comment: Thanks.  Along the way, you hit a third recurrence in Somos's list, $a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) - a(n-3)+1$.  Since this nice method subtracts away the various inhomogeneous terms, I'd guess it's not reversible.  I.e., from $a(n) = 2a(n-1)-2a(n-3)+a(n-4)$, one doesn't easily get $a(n) = a(n-2) + n - 1$.

Comment: One problem here is that if $C,D$ are any constants then $a(n)=a(n-2)+Cn+D$ leads to $a(n)=2a(n-1)-2a(n-3)+a(n-4)$, so the passage from homogeneous to inhomogeneous doesn't yield a unique result, but rather a two-parameter family of results.